# Ident Romeo and Juliet song

Tags: identify-this-song

I can’t find the cruddy radio copy mp3 I used to have anymore but the first verse goes like this:

> My Juliet..
>
> I was your Romeo you were my Juliet
>   and we were so in love.
>   It was instant love.
>
> 1,2,3,4
>   It was late night party time when I first set eyes on you.
>   I saw you across the room
>   when I did my heart went boom.
>   That first kiss it filled me so,
>   so won't you let me be your romeo
>   and you can be my juliet.
>   You were dressed as an angel of God
>   and looking beautiful you know.
>   Your dress was as white as snow
>   I wanted to kiss you owh ow owh owh.
>
> I was your Romeo you were my Juliet
>   and we were so in love.
>   It was instant love.
>
> Now I know how Romeo felt
>   when he first met Juliet.
>   It was love, love at first sight,
>   I'm feeling romantic tonight.

It would have been either late 80s or very early 90s. Male singer. It was typical pop music style with a fast beat.

Obviously I tried Googling it, but the only thing that comes up is the stupid false positive lyrster.com and some super old unanswered forums.

Answer (score 1):

i have a feeling I know this song from 90's! It took me a while to find it (very hard to find anything Romeo & Juliet related!!! It depends exactly which word you choose and how you quote them - I found it by google this way (this is what I remember of that song):

> "i am your juliet you are my romeo"

And I found it! :-) Slightly different lyrics, but could it be this one? Movetron: Romeo and Juliet (1995) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqfBNCU3PPA

Comment: This is not the song, the lyrics are completely different except for the similarity with the one quoted line.

Answer (score -1):

Blue System "Romeo and Juliet " from 1992

Comment: is there a video ? a link would make the answer easier to read

Comment: This is not the song, the lyrics do not match at all.